# Print the first column of multiple files using awk

Tags: awk

I have 20 files, I want to print the first column of each file into a different file.I need 20 output files.

i have tried the following command, but this one puts all the output into a single file.

```
awk '{print $1}' /home/gee/SNP_data/20* > out_file
```

write the output to different files, i have 20 input files

Comment: For those with close/reopen votes privilege: [Bash- Read and print multiple files using loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58651250/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus, Hello sir, I could close it as Dup. But when I checked the link mentioned I could see solutions only for appending output are given but here OP is saying to have 20 output files, so IMHO it looks different from this link, if any other link is there for same, will be closing it as a dup.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: The link should serve to understand the background of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  if(file){
    close(file)
  }
  file="out_file_"FILENAME".txt"
}
{
  print $1 > (file)
}
' /home/gee/SNP_data/20*
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                     ##Starting awk program here.
FNR==1{                                   ##checking condition if FNR==1 then do following.
  if(file){                               ##Checking condition if variable file is NOT NULL then do following.
    close(file)                           ##Using close to close the opened output file in backend, to avoid too many opened files error.
  }                                       ##Closing BLOCK for if condition.
  file="out_file_"FILENAME".txt"          ##Setting variable file value to string out_file_ then FILENAME(which is Input_file) and append .txt to it.
}                                         ##Closing BLOCK for condition for FNR==1 here.
{
  print $1 > (file)                       ##Printing first field to variable file here.
}
' /home/gee/SNP_data/20*                  ##Mentioning Input_file path here to pass files here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you need to get output files like `output_file_1.txt`  ans so on then try following. I have created an awk variable named `out_file` where you could change your output file's name's initial too(as per your need).

```
awk -v out_file="Output_file_" '
FNR==1{
  if(file){
    close(file)
  }
  ++count
  file=out_file count".txt"
}
{
  print $1 > (file)
}
' /home/gee/SNP_data/20*
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk has a builtin redirection operator, you can use it like:

```
awk '{ print $1 > ("out_" FILENAME) }' /home/gee/SNP_data/20*
```

or, even better:

```
awk 'FNR==1 { close(f); f=("out_" FILENAME) } { print $1 > f }' /home/gee/SNP_data/20*
```

Former is just an example usage of redirection operator, latter is how to use it robustly.